# How do I rebuild an empty Visual Studio 2017 toolbox - WInForms

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, toolbox

I am hoping someone can provide a little insight.

I am working with a Visual Basis WinForms application using **Visual Studio 2017** on **Windows 10**.

I had a Toolbox with several custom objects.

While testing the application, VS completely froze.  With no other alternate approach presented itself, I decided to abort VS via Task Manager.

When I restarted VS, I discovered that the Toolbox was empty.  Not just my custom objects; in fact, all the standard objects were gone as well.   When I clicked "Show Objects", I saw both the standard objects as well as my custom ones listed, but they were completely disabled (grayed out) and not selectable.

I researched several tickets regarding similar issues on **StackOverflow** and tried all the following approaches, without any success:

1. Clicked **Reset Toolbox**, deleted the toolbox "**.tbd**" files and
   restarted VS.
2. Reinstalled, upgraded and restarted VS.
3. Changed the Project Type from **Windows Application** to **Class Library** and then
   back again.
4. Restarted VS ("**devenv.exe /ResetSettings**", "**devenv.exe /SafeMode**")

If I create a brand new **Windows Application**, the toolbox builds in the correct items.

How do I get the toolbox to build correctly for my current solution/application?  I do not want to have to create a brand new application as the application is an established and very large one, and rebuilding is not an option.

Any insights and/or suggestions would, of course, be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Chris Fleetwood
cfleetwood@smartstart.org

Comment: Delete the .suo file, https://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/02/solving-project-file-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path-with-visual-studio/#:~:text=In%20Visual%20Studio%202015%20%28also%20in%20Community%20Edition%29%2C,options%20to%20%E2%80%9Cshow%20hidden%20files%2C%20folders%20and%20drives%E2%80%9D.

Comment: @HansPassant  That worked!  Thank you sir.  Voting your answer up.